# Locally free sheaf on Cohen-Macaulay scheme and Serre's criterion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

Let $X$ be a projective locally Cohen-Macaulay scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ be a locally free sheaf on $X$. If I understand correctly the definition of Serre's criterion $S_k$, $\mathcal{F}$ satisifies $S_k$ for all $k \ge 0$. Is this correct?

Comment: A nitpick: "locally Cohen-Macaulay" is redundant: Cohen-Macaulay is a condition on local rings of points. More seriously, this should suggest that the whole question is local.

Comment: Actually, I often use the term "locally Cohen-Macaulay" in order to distinguish it from "projectively Cohen-Macaulay."